# RadioButton switch to update check box label

Tags: python, maya

Want to setup a radio button when button state change to update text label.
Here the code bolow. Thanks a lot.

```py
import maya.cmds  as cmds
import pymel.core as pm

class Ui():
    def __init__(self):
        windowID = 'testWin'
        uiName   = "Test Win"

        if pm.window(windowID, exists=1):
            pm.deleteUI(windowID)

        tmpl = pm.uiTemplate(windowID+'_uiTmpl', force=1)

        
        wnd = pm.window(windowID, t=uiName, s=1, rtf=1, toolbox=1)

        with tmpl:
            with pm.horizontalLayout() as skinLayout1:                    
                pm.radioCollection("tmp")
                pm.radioButton("tmpX", l="X", da=0, onc=self.switchCmd())
                pm.radioButton("tmpY", l="Y", da=1, onc=self.switchCmd(), sl=1)
                pm.radioButton("tmpZ", l="Z", da=2, onc=self.switchCmd())
                pm.checkBox("checkBox", l="X", v=1)
                
        wnd.show()
    
    
    def switchCmd(self, *arg):
        if pm.radioButton("tmpX", q=1, sl=1) == 1:
            dir = "Z"
        elif pm.radioButton("tmpY", q=1, sl=1)== 1:
            dir = "X"
        elif pm.radioButton("tmpZ", q=1, sl=1) == 1:
            dir = "Y"
        
        pm.checkBox("checkBox", e=1, l=dir)
        
        return

Ui()
```

Now I tried to code and got errors.
"RuntimeError: Object 'tmpX' not found."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your on command is not defined correctly, if you use self.switchCmd() the method will be executed directly, you will have to use onc=self.switchCmd without parentheses.